# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to - Error

Tags: ora-06550

I am getting following error when calling a oracle plsql procedure using spring jdbc in java.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call "Procedure name"; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'procedure_name'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This procedure exist under a package A in schema S1. I have created a synonym in schema S2 for this package A and trying to execute this procedure using spring SimpleJdbcCall, with schema name S2 but it's giving me the above error.

But when i execute this query using SqlPlus in schema S2, this procedure executes fine, it means there is no grant issue with this.

When i execute the same procedure with the Schema name where it actually exists (S1) then also it executes fine using spring-java.

Is there any issue related to synonym created in Schema S2 for this package A??

Am i missing anything here?

Comment: "*Am i missing anything here*" - the code (or at least the signature) of the stored procedure and the code that _calls_ the stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue and like you explicitly declared the parameters. The fix was to additionally specify:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
    ...
```

My assumption is that the synonym is preventing the parameter inference from **working** without actually stopping it **happening** and as a result the driver concludes that the stored procedure does not accept any parameters and therefore does not send any.

Old question so I know this won't help the OP but hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: This helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code (both the PLSQL and Java side), I would have to say that the procedure has required parameters (no DEFAULT value for a parameter) that you are not supplying in the Java code or the name of the parameter in the procedure does not match the name you used in Java.

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure Spec**

```
PROCEDURE procedure1(value   OUT NUMBER,
                                userId      IN  NUMBER,
                                returnCursor OUT PackageA.Types.cursorType);
```

**Java-Code**

```
SimpleJdbcCall optOutCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
            .withSchemaName("Schema-A")
            .withCatalogName("PackageA")
            .withProcedureName(procedure1)
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("value", Types.NUMERIC),
                               new SqlParameter("userId", Types.NUMERIC))
            .returningResultSet("returnCursor", new UserMapper(EnumType.EMAIL, userId));
```

This "procedure1" exists in Schema-B but i have created a synonym for this procedure in Schema-A and i am trying to execute this procedure
using 'Schema-A' but it throws error,  if i give the schema name "Schema-B" in java code then it executes correctly and returns the results.